# Text Based Game Python - Get Item Function

Tags: python, game-development

I was working on this coding project for school maybe 2-3 months ago, and I haven't really touched python since my introductory scripting course. I'm looking to move this project onto my portfolio, however I can't really figure out why my get item function won't work, and my professor at the time didn't offer any helpful hints or advice when asked. Please be kind. I was a noob when it came to coding and it was my first big project.

The problem:
Basically, once you are in the room it will indicate that there is an item present. If you type "get item" it will show you what item is in the room. However, my code doesn't allow for you to add it into your inventory and move rooms afterwards. You're just stuck in the loop. Also once the item is introduced you are unable to use the 'exit' if statement to break the loop.

My move between rooms function worked fine before adding the get item function.

I think the error might be one of the following things:

1. It might have to do with every room having an item besides the starting room. I don't know a work around for that besides putting in a dummy item for that room such as 'None'. Which is something I don't really want to do.
2. It might have to do with the "directions_available" because the item is showing in the directional movements.
3. Some other error?

```
# The Battle of Ollion Nation.

import time  # imported time for sleep delays.

# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
    'Arvandor Campground': {'South': 'Wilderness', 'East': 'Medic Area'},
    'Wilderness': {'North': 'Arvandor Campground', 'East': 'Riverfront', 'West': 'Foraging Area',
                   'South': 'Mountain Trail', 'item': 'Wooden Staff'},
    'Medic Area': {'West': 'Arvandor Campground', 'item': 'Enchantment Potion & Spell Book'},
    'Foraging Area': {'East': 'Wilderness', 'item': 'Nightshade Leaves'},
    'Crystal Cavern': {'South': 'Riverfront', 'item': 'Emerald'},
    'Riverfront': {'North': 'Crystal Cavern', 'West': 'Wilderness', 'item': 'Cattail Leaves'},
    'Mountain Trail': {'North': 'Wilderness', 'East': 'Eryn Campgrounds', 'item': 'silver'},
    'Eryn Campgrounds': {'West': 'Mountain Trail', 'item': 'Thalor'}  # villain
}


# user is prompted to enter their name to start the game.
print('Greetings! Please enter your name to start: ')

# user will enter their name to continue.
player_name = input()


# define game instructions.
def game_instructions():
    print('Welcome to the Ollion Nation,', player_name, '.')
    print('As a member of the Arvandor tribe, your quest is to find the broken pieces and other resources')
    print('to assemble the ancient nature staff that was depleted in the last great battle against the Eryn.')
    print('At the end you will face your rival, Thalor leader of the Eryn, in a great battle to claim the')
    print('forest of Ollion as your own.')
    print('-----------------------------')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Travel Commands: North, South, East, or West.')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'.")
    print("Type 'Exit' to end the game.")
    print('Good luck!')
    print('-----------------------------')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)


# player will start at the Arvandor Campgrounds.
current_room = 'Arvandor Campground'


# defines the player movement through the map.
def move_room(current_room, rooms):
    new_room = current_room
    # Loop and if valid direction
    # assign new room
    for i in rooms:
        if i == current_room:
            if directions in rooms[current_room]:
                new_room = rooms[current_room][player_input]
    # Return new location
    return new_room


inventory = []  # creates an empty list for the inventory


def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        return rooms[current_room]['item']
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!'


# directions for moving through the rooms.
directions = ['North', 'South', 'West', 'East']
# prints the game instructions for player.
game_instructions()
# initialize player input as nothing - gives the user the option to input data.
player_input = ''

# starts the game loop. As long as player does not say Exit the loop will play.
while 1:
    # shows the player their current room.
    print("Your current location is: ", current_room)
    # shows the player their current inventory.
    print('Current Inventory: ', inventory)
    # shows the player the available directions they can go.
    directions_available = ', '.join(rooms[current_room].keys())
    print("Available directions: ", directions_available)
    # asks the player for input on direction or to grab item.
    player_input = input("What would you like to do?: ")
    print("You've typed: ", player_input)
    player_input = player_input.capitalize()

    item = rooms[current_room].get('item')

    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:  # used to see which item is in the room.
        print()
        print("You see something lying on the ground. It's the", rooms[current_room]['item'])
        print()
    elif len(inventory) != 6 and 'item' == 'Thalor':
        print('Thalor says: You thought you could beat me with that? How hilairous.')
        print('You and your tribe vow to return once the staff is renewed, until then you return defeated.')
        exit(0)     # validation for losing the game.
    elif len(inventory) == 6 and 'item' == 'Thalor':    # validation for winning the game.
        print('Thalor falls to your feet. The rest of his tribe decides that its better to run than face you.')
        print('Congratulations on your victory.')
        exit(0)
    elif player_input == 'get' and rooms[current_room]['item'].capitalize():
        if item in inventory:    # inventory validation
            print('You already have this item.')
        else:
            print("You now have the", 'item', "in your possession.")
            inventory.append(item)
        print(inventory)

    elif player_input in directions:
        if player_input in directions_available:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][player_input]  # moves player to their new location.
            print('-------------------')
            print('You have moved to the', current_room)
            print('-------------------')
        else:
            print()
            print('That doesnt look like the correct path. Lets try another way.')  # validation for invalid move.
            print()
    elif player_input == 'Exit' or player_input == 'exit':  # exit game
        print('-------------------')
        print('That was a valiant effort. Thanks for playing.')
        break
    else:
        print()
        print("I dont understand that command. Try again.")  # validation for invalid commands.
        print()
```

I have also tried the below code which I'll most likely build off of because its a bit cleaner for game play.

I put the directions in a main function, and sort of changed the case validation for winning and losing the game, changed the get item function, etc.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
# The Battle of Ollion Nation.

import time  # imported time for sleep delays.

# user is prompted to enter their name to start the game.
print('Greetings! Please enter your name to start: ')

# user will enter their name to continue.
player_name = input().title()

# define game instructions.
def game_instructions():
    print('Welcome to the Ollion Nation,', player_name, '.')
    print('As a member of the Arvandor tribe, your quest is to find the broken pieces and other resources')
    print('to assemble the ancient nature staff that was depleted in the last great battle against the Eryn.')
    print('At the end you will face your rival, Thalor leader of the Eryn, in a great battle to claim the')
    print('forest of Ollion as your own.')
    print('-----------------------------')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Travel Commands: North, South, East, or West.')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'.")
    print("Type 'Exit' to end the game.")
    print('Good luck!')
    print('-----------------------------')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

# directions for moving through the rooms.
directions = ['North', 'South', 'West', 'East']
# initialize player input as nothing - gives the user the option to input data.
player_input = ''

# defines the player movement through the map.
def move_room(current_room, rooms):
    new_room = current_room
    # Loop and if valid direction
    # assign new room
    for i in rooms:
        if i == current_room:
           if directions in rooms[current_room]:
               new_room = rooms[current_room][player_input]
    # Return new location
        return new_room

#adds item to the inventory and removes it from the room. 
def get_item(current_room, player_input, rooms, inventory): 
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']

 
def main():
    # dictionary of connecting rooms with items
    rooms = {
        'Arvandor Campground': {'South': 'Wilderness', 'East': 'Medic Area'},
        'Wilderness': {'North': 'Arvandor Campground', 'East': 'Riverfront', 'West': 'Foraging Area', 'South': 'Mountain Trail', 'item': 'Wooden Staff'},
        'Medic Area': {'West': 'Arvandor Campground', 'item': 'Enchantment Potion & Spell Book'},
        'Foraging Area': {'East': 'Wilderness', 'item': 'Nightshade Leaves'},
        'Crystal Cavern': {'South': 'Riverfront', 'item': 'Emerald'},
        'Riverfront': {'North': 'Crystal Cavern', 'West': 'Wilderness', 'item': 'Cattail Leaves'},
        'Mountain Trail': {'North': 'Wilderness', 'East': 'Eryn Campgrounds', 'item': 'silver'},
        'Eryn Campgrounds': {'West': 'Mountain Trail', 'item': 'Thalor'}  # villain
    }

    # creates an empty list for the inventory
    inventory = []
    # player will start at the Arvandor Campgrounds.
    current_room = 'Arvandor Campground'
    # prints the game instructions for player.
    game_instructions()

# starts the game loop. As long as player does not say Exit the loop will play.
    while True:
        # shows the player their current room.
        print("Your current location is: ", current_room)
        # shows the player their current inventory.
        print('Current Inventory: ', inventory)
        # shows the player the available directions they can go.
        directions_available = ', '.join(rooms[current_room].keys())
        print("Available directions: ", directions_available)
        # asks the player for input on direction or to grab item.
        player_input = input("What would you like to do?: ").title()

        item = rooms[current_room].get('item')

        # case for when the player meets the villian.
        if current_room == 'Eryn Campgrounds': 
            # validation for winning the game.
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('Thalor falls to your feet. The rest of his tribe decides that its better to run than face you.')
                print('Congratulations on your victory.')
                break
            # validation for losing the game.
            else:
                print('Thalor says: You thought you could beat me with that? How hilairous.')
                print('You and your tribe vow to return once the staff is renewed, until then you return defeated.')
                print('Thanks for playing.')
                break
        # used to see which item is in the room.
        elif current_room != 'Eryn Campgrounds' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys(): 
            print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            print("You see something lying on the ground. It's the {}".format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        # inventory validation
        elif player_input == ('Get ').join(player_input[1:]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('-----------------------------------------------------')
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            print('-----------------------------------------------------')
            get_item(current_room, player_input, rooms, inventory)
            continue
        # moves player to their new location.
        elif player_input in directions:
             if player_input in directions_available:
                 current_room = rooms[current_room][player_input]  
                 print('------------------------------------')
                 print("You've typed: ", player_input)
                 print('You have moved to the', current_room)
                 print('------------------------------------')
            # validation for invalid move.
             else:
                 print('-------------------------------------------------------------')
                 print('That doesnt look like the correct path. Lets try another way.')
                 print('-------------------------------------------------------------')

        # exit game
        elif player_input == 'Exit' or player_input == 'exit':
            print('----------------------------------------------')
            print('That was a valiant effort. Thanks for playing.')
            print('----------------------------------------------')
            break
        # validation for invalid commands.
        else:
            print()
            print("I dont understand that command. Try again.") 
            print()


main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't provide debugging services. Use the following references to narrow your problem by debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: I can't tell which version of the code you're asking for help with, or what the actual problem is.  I do notice that in the first version of your code you `capitalize` the input, and then you test it for equivalence to lowercase strings like `'get'` which obviously it will never be equal to if it's just been capitalized...

Comment: @Samwise Honestly, whichever code actually works is the one I'm going with at this point. Thanks for the feedback. Even after changing 'Get' to be capitalized I still run into the same issue. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a good hard look at your main gameloop, and how you're deciding to react to user input. In this case (the second code), after traveling either south or east from the starting location you're satisfying the first `elif` condition which doesn't really allow you to progress (it only prints out some text).

```
elif current_room != 'Eryn Campgrounds' and 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
```

Python's `if: elif: else:` will only ever execute one of the blocks (the first which is satisfied), so if the first `elif` is satisfied, none of the others will be evaluated. In this case you may need to simply start a new `if` rather than continuing with more `elif`'s. Carefully consider the flow for how you need to treat each iteration of the game loop (maybe make a flow chart to help).

In either case it's beneficial to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line so you can see that it's following the flow you expect. Some IDE's also let you view currently defined variables as well as their value as you do this so you can know why a given `elif` statement may or may not be satisfied. I happen to use the Spyder IDE, which has both these features, and there are videos you can search on how to use them.

Comment: Hey Aaron, this was literally so helpful. I'll take a deeper look into the IF/ELIF statements. When I first created this code, I thought you would start the loop with your first IF statement and every IF statement afterwards was an ELIF. Total misunderstanding on my part. I'll look into the Spyder IDE as well because that sounds like exactly what I need.